# Constructors for Auto Generated EDMX class in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, constructor, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, auto-generate

I have an auto generated context class in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project. I want some operation to be done on object creation of this class. Instead of editing the constructor in this auto generated class(Which I heard is not recommended) , Is there some other way to do this ?

When I use,

```
  var cntx = new DataBaseEntities();
```

I want some other operation to be taken care of. but This DatabaseEntities is an auto generated class. Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

The best I can suggest is a factory method:

```
private DataBaseEntities(string contextName) : base(contextName) { }

public static DataBaseEntities Create() {
    return new DataBaseEntities(ContextName);
}
```

and use DataBaseEntities.Create() rather than new DataBaseEntities()

```
var cntx = new DataBaseEntities.Create();
```